# Alexa python get request returns null. Lambda is fine

Tags: python, python-requests, aws-lambda, alexa-skills-kit

Hi I am trying to get a respond from Alexa requesting on a backend using requests. I am using Python with these example: https://github.com/alexa/skill-sample-python-fact. However my backend is NodeJS.

From my Lambda:

```
URL = 'https://alexa-app-nikko.herokuapp.com/alexa'

def get_post_response():
    r = requests.get(URL)

    speech_output = str(r.text)
    return response(speech_response(speech_output, True))
```

On my backend, it is routed to /alexa:

```
router.get('/', function(request, response) {
    //console.log('Logged from Alexa.');
    response.send('Hello World, Alexa!');
});
```

I tested it on the Lambda and works fine with these results:

```
{
  "version": "1.0",
  "response": {
    "outputSpeech": {
      "type": "PlainText",
      "text": "Hello World, Alexa!"
    },
    "shouldEndSession": true
  }
}
```

However I get a `null` on the Skill Output or this response from Alexa:

```
"There was a problem with the requested skill's response"
```

How do I debug from the Developer Console, because it seems the Lambda is fine.

Comment: It's a long shot, but have you enabled the skill for the region you are in.

Comment: When you test via Alexa, do the Lambda logs show the same response as when you test directly from Lambda?

Comment: Welp, Im from the PH. But I am using the N. Virginia for the skill as the default region to enable to Alexa Skills Kit. @LornaMitchell

Comment: @KMo How will I do that? So I can see a real-time log from Lambda other than the test?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on your own answer :

The problem is, when you invoke the `LaunchIntent` or other intents like `AMAZON.StopIntent` it doesn't have the key `"slots"` in them. And you were trying to access the value of `slots` which should throw a **KeyError**.

What you can do is, when you're sure of invocation of any particular intent which uses some slots, then you try to access them.

This is what I do :

```
def getSlotValue(intent, slot):
    if 'slots' in intent:
        if slot in intent['slots']:
            if 'value' in intent['slots'][slot] and len(intent['slots'][slot]['value']) > 0:
                return intent['slots'][slot]['value']

    return -1
```

And try to access the slot values in your intent's function (in your `get_post_response` or `get_power_response`).

Comment: Ohhh Yeaaah. Because it only appears on Intents which has slots on it. Otherwise none and throw a KeyError. Thanks for this.

Answer (score 0):

I do not know what is the connection of this problem to my request. It is now working.

```
def on_intent(request, session):
    """ called on receipt of an Intent  """

    intent_name = request['intent']['name']
    #intent_slots = request['intent']['slots']

    # process the intents
    if intent_name == "DebugIntent":
        return get_debug_response()
    elif intent_name == "PostIntent":
        return get_post_response()
    elif intent_name == "PowerIntent":
        return get_power_response(request)
        #return get_power_response(intent_slots)
# ----------- Amazon Built-in Intents -----------------
    elif intent_name == "AMAZON.HelpIntent":
        return get_help_response()
    elif intent_name == "AMAZON.StopIntent":
        return get_stop_response()
    elif intent_name == "AMAZON.CancelIntent":
        return get_stop_response()
    elif intent_name == "AMAZON.FallbackIntent":
        return get_fallback_response()
    else:
        print("invalid Intent reply with help")
        return get_help_response()
```

I debugged it and what I got was a problem with the keyword 'slots' so I removed in my code the `intent_slots = request['intent']['slots']` which I was also using to pass it to another function `return get_power_response(intent_slots)`. I commented it out and replace or just placed the original `request` from `def on_intent(request, session):`.